# training Neural Network, why is model.add not working?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Trying to create neural network for my model but "model.add" is not working. Would really appreciate any help. I tried without model.add and it works so it has to do with adding to the model. Would appreciate any help :)

```
model = Sequential()
# A bunch of code between this
ink = (1, 64, 120, 1)
ink = tf.random.normal(ink)

#l2
model.add(Conv2D(20, (64, 1), activation="relu", input_shape=(64, 120, 1)))
```

Here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
   1852   try:
-> 1853     c_op = pywrap_tf_session.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
   1854   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 64 from 1 for '{{node conv2d_5/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](Placeholder, conv2d_5/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,1,120,20], [64,1,20,20].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
17 frames
<ipython-input-19-398c7d9e7631> in <module>()
      3 
      4 #l2
----> 5 model.add(Conv2D(20, (64, 1), activation="relu", input_shape=(64, 120, 1)))
      6 # # print(L2.shape) #0th index: # of batches, 1st index: height of output, 2nd index: width of output, 3rd index: depth -> # of filters
      7 # #l3

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    515     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    516     try:
--> 517       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    518     finally:
    519       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py in add(self, layer)
    221       # If the model is being built continuously on top of an input layer:
    222       # refresh its output.
--> 223       output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
    224       if len(nest.flatten(output_tensor)) != 1:
    225         raise ValueError(SINGLE_LAYER_OUTPUT_ERROR_MSG)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    950     if _in_functional_construction_mode(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list):
    951       return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, args, kwargs,
--> 952                                                 input_list)
    953 
    954     # Maintains info about the `Layer.call` stack.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _functional_construction_call(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list)
   1089         # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
   1090         outputs = self._keras_tensor_symbolic_call(
-> 1091             inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
   1092 
   1093         if outputs is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call(self, inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
    820       return nest.map_structure(keras_tensor.KerasTensor, output_signature)
    821     else:
--> 822       return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    823 
    824   def _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    861           # TODO(kaftan): do we maybe_build here, or have we already done it?
    862           self._maybe_build(inputs)
--> 863           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    864 
    865         self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py in call(self, inputs)
    246       inputs = array_ops.pad(inputs, self._compute_causal_padding(inputs))
    247 
--> 248     outputs = self._convolution_op(inputs, self.kernel)
    249 
    250     if self.use_bias:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    199     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    200     try:
--> 201       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    202     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py in convolution_v2(input, filters, strides, padding, data_format, dilations, name)
   1018       data_format=data_format,
   1019       dilations=dilations,
-> 1020       name=name)
   1021 
   1022 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py in convolution_internal(input, filters, strides, padding, data_format, dilations, name, call_from_convolution, num_spatial_dims)
   1148           data_format=data_format,
   1149           dilations=dilations,
-> 1150           name=name)
   1151     else:
   1152       if channel_index == 1:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py in _conv2d_expanded_batch(input, filters, strides, padding, data_format, dilations, name)
   2602         data_format=data_format,
   2603         dilations=dilations,
-> 2604         name=name)
   2605   return squeeze_batch_dims(
   2606       input,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py in conv2d(input, filter, strides, padding, use_cudnn_on_gpu, explicit_paddings, data_format, dilations, name)
    971                   padding=padding, use_cudnn_on_gpu=use_cudnn_on_gpu,
    972                   explicit_paddings=explicit_paddings,
--> 973                   data_format=data_format, dilations=dilations, name=name)
    974   _result = _outputs[:]
    975   if _execute.must_record_gradient():

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    748       op = g._create_op_internal(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None,
    749                                  name=scope, input_types=input_types,
--> 750                                  attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
    751 
    752     # `outputs` is returned as a separate return value so that the output

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in _create_op_internal(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_device)
    590     return super(FuncGraph, self)._create_op_internal(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    591         op_type, captured_inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def,
--> 592         compute_device)
    593 
    594   def capture(self, tensor, name=None, shape=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_op_internal(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_device)
   3534           input_types=input_types,
   3535           original_op=self._default_original_op,
-> 3536           op_def=op_def)
   3537       self._create_op_helper(ret, compute_device=compute_device)
   3538     return ret

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __init__(self, node_def, g, inputs, output_types, control_inputs, input_types, original_op, op_def)
   2014         op_def = self._graph._get_op_def(node_def.op)
   2015       self._c_op = _create_c_op(self._graph, node_def, inputs,
-> 2016                                 control_input_ops, op_def)
   2017       name = compat.as_str(node_def.name)
   2018     # pylint: enable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
   1854   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
   1855     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
-> 1856     raise ValueError(str(e))
   1857 
   1858   return c_op

ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 64 from 1 for '{{node conv2d_5/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](Placeholder, conv2d_5/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,1,120,20], [64,1,20,20].
```

***Edit 2***
Here is the Model: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1L0n4sqeS3_ugRtDdUYDzvTOpmfl_A9cA?usp=sharing

Comment: Would you mind showing the error?

Comment: @YashvanderBamel I apologize. Just added it.

Comment: FYI, Question does not reproduce the error. Is this the whole model?

Comment: @Frightera I linked the full model. Would really appreciate your help!

Comment: I couldn't get which part throws this error, but adding same padding can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with a Sequential model, you need to compile the model like this:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
# A bunch of code between this
ink = (1, 64, 120, 1)
ink = tf.random.normal(ink)

#l2
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(20, (64, 1), activation="relu", input_shape=(64, 120, 1)))

# compiling the model - to train you need define optimizer
model.compile()

# doing prediction
model.predict(ink)
```

The result with using initialized weights:

```
array([[[[0.        , 0.20018369, 0.        , ..., 0.17063043,
          0.        , 0.306499  ],
         [0.33700752, 0.13667333, 0.06687334, ..., 0.        ,
          0.        , 0.        ],
         [0.        , 0.        , 0.18594216, ..., 0.        ,
          0.        , 0.601507  ],
         ...,
         [0.        , 0.04625941, 0.13538724, ..., 0.18879202,
          0.        , 0.05151432],
         [0.15855402, 0.29250288, 0.        , ..., 0.31243593,
          0.        , 0.        ],
         [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        ,
          0.        , 0.        ]]]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: The given error in the question should occur before compiling.